# how to convert the string to date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I AM FACING ONE PROBLEM.

I AM USING BELOW METHOD FOR MAKING STRING VALUE TO DATE.
string values is like this =`"01/12/2002" like "dd/MM/YYYY"`

My problem is that.

two string values

->1)01/01/2025
->2)1/1/2025

i am getting the Value like above 1 or 2

```
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dumm, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
```

if 1 comes nothing will happen but 
if i get 2 i am facing error like String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
As per my Analysts what i understood is  date should be 2 digits Remaining all are two digits other wise giving the error.
but some times i am getting single digits from the excel to vb.net

## how can i solve this issue...

```
Dim dumm As String = DtSet3.Tables(0).Rows(k + 0).Item(3).ToString
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dumm, "d/M/yyyy", Nothing)
```

i put the break point on dumm ok dumm vlaues= "1/2/2026 12:00:00 Am"

Error...............

now

```
Dim dumm As String = DtSet3.Tables(0).Rows(k + 0).Item(3).ToString
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2026", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
```

Working Fine.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date format string **"d/M/yyyy h:m:s tt"**. This will handle both cases i.e. with and without leading zero for the day and month. Additionally, since your actual variable has a time component in addition to the date, you need to add the format string for parsing time as well.

However, I would advise you to use `TryParseExact`, which will return boolean values based on success or failure of the parse rather than throwing exceptions.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NMIPG35642) for using `TryParseExact` along with appropriate format string.

Comment: Not working same Error.  Dim dumm As String = DtSet3.Tables(0).Rows(k + 0).Item(3).ToString
                ' Dim dd As Date = CDate(dumm)

                Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2026", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)

Comment: Did you read my answer and also check my demo link? I said **"d/M/yyyy"**. You are using **"dd/MM/yyyy"**

Comment: 'This is my coding dumm is comming from excel sheet ok. 
   i put the break point and chekc the value of dumm = 1/2/2026 12:00:00 am
  Dim dumm As String = DtSet3.Tables(0).Rows(k + 0).Item(3).ToString
  Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dumm, "d/M/yyyy", Nothing)
  but giving the error


  Now i changed the code 
  Dim dumm As String = DtSet3.Tables(0).Rows(k + 0).Item(3).ToString
  Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2026", "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
  but giving the error
  Now working
  Any information...

Comment: @SrinivasRachumallu Please put all this into your question by editing it. Comments are not the right place to put your code. Also, did you try debugging and see what is the actual value of `dumm`?